# Responsive html not responding when put in smaller container

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have some HTML, and the size looks fine when viewing in desktop mode and also shrinks appropriately when viewed on a mobile screen, as I would expect.

I went to also place this HTML in a smaller container(col-md-6), but I notice that it appears as 100% screen width, I would have thought that it would have shrunk, i.e. responsive would have kicked in and displayed as if in mobile view.

Is there anything that can be done to force it to display in smaller mobile view on the desktop in a certain container rather than resizing the screen?

Thanks

Comment: You need to share your code. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: This is most likely something that some with good experience in css and responsive design would know straight away. It's a pretty straightforward question that shouldn't require any code..which would be way too large anyway. If you don't know the answer, don't comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the width on your viewport tag with 'device-width'. Then bootstrap will work as advertised. Like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```